# Android NDK include of math.h gives "use of undeclared identifier" error

Tags: android-ndk, visual-studio-2017, clang

I've a solution containing two project types .androidproj (Android) and .vcxproj (C++) in my Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. I use `android-ndk-r13b` for the C++ part.

Since the update from Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition version `15.5.7` to `15.6.1` ([release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes)) I experience the following blocking error:

```
error : use of undeclared identifier 'acosl'
```

See the representing lines in the build output:

```
In file included from C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b\sources\android\support\include\math.h:31:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\math.h(661,91): error : use of undeclared identifier 'acosl'
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY long double acos(long double __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return acosl(__lcpp_x);}
```

Next to the `acosl` also all other math functions are not found.

Unfortunately those Posts didn't help in my case:

- [Visual Studio 2015, Android NDK with libc++ and cmath issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962780/visual-studio-2015-android-ndk-with-libc-and-cmath-issues)
- [Visual Studio 2017 Android NDK math.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137308/visual-studio-2017-android-ndk-math-h)

Any hints what I could try?

**Update**

The `minSdkVersion` is set to `15`. The solution compiled before the Visual Studio update without errors.

Comment: What's your `minSdkVersion`? `acosl` wasn't available until android-21.

Comment: The `minSdkVersion` is set to `15`. I want to mention that the exact same solution compiled before the Visual Studio update.